# KVM switch with 2x USB C inputs and dual 4K monitor support

Tags: multiple-monitors, macbook-pro, kvm-switch, usb-c, thunderbolt

I've been looking for a KVM switch for a while that would support connecting two MacBooks
(via a single USB-C input from each) to two 4K monitors. The idea is to be able to switch between the two laptops and be able to use the two monitors and mouse/keyboard. I've seen several options but they either don't support USB-C input, or are a single monitor output. Any recommendations, or workarounds? This is my setup:

**Laptops (2x):** *MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019) w/ AMD Radeon Pro 5500M 8 GB Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB.*

**Monitors (2x):** *Sceptre 35 Inch Curved UltraWide 21: 9 LED Creative Monitor QHD 3440x1440 Frameless AMD Freesync HDMI DisplayPort Up to 100Hz, Machine Black 2020 (C355W-3440UN).*

**Preipherals:** *USB Mouse & USB Keyboard.*

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In case anyone else stumbles into this, I found this KVM solution and it works perfectly. Exactly what I was looking for.

https://www.visiontek.com/products/vt4900-kvm-usb-c-docking-station-dual-host-100w-power-delivery-triple-4k-display?variant=40553091858581

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1101562)